# Error in IIS/SQL Server: Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2003

I have asp.net 2 asp.net websites hosted on windows 2003 server.

My database(sql server 2008 standard) is 4Gb (only 250MB are free). The server hard disc is 34Gb(with 6GB free).

A few days ago I tried to access my website when sql server profiler is running. After some actions in the website, I got the following message:

> Not enough storage is available to process this command

Can you tell what can be the reason?

I have to mention that after I ran the `iisreset` command, I saw the website working well again, but I'm afraid it will occur again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a disk storage issue.  There are a bunch of causes of this error, but basically from a problem with a pooled resource and ultimately this is an IIS/OS problem.

https://serverfault.com/questions/147526/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think I need to use the suggested methods, as it occurred only 1 time, so I'll better not make any significant changes. You said that it's not a storage issue, does it mean that the DB free space is not the issue as well?

Comment: @benams Unless the database logs indicate that as being involved in some way (database space issues are usually obvious - log full, can't grow file, etc), no.  You should be able to see more information in the Windows event logs and the SQL Server event logs.